# EclipseLink Generates Duplicate Primary Keys

Tags: oracle, jpa, oracle11g, glassfish, eclipselink

I've been looking at this all afternoon and I'm stumped.  Why is EclipseLink using duplicate values?  How can it?

This entity class had worked fine using Hibernate, but I'm trying to get the app running under Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

The application fails with:

```
[#|2013-11-04T15:54:17.190-0700|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/foo_jar/_bar.sql|_ThreadID=143;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (GAPM.SYS_C0033927) violated

Error Code: 1
Call: INSERT INTO TIME_DIMENSION (ID, DAY_OF_MONTH, DAY_OF_WEEK, DAY_OF_YEAR, HOUR, JWK_WEEK, JWK_YEAR, MINUTE, MONTH, MONTH_NAME, QUARTER, WEEKDAY, YEAR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [3565649, 4, 1, 308, 19, 45, 2013, 7, 11, November, 2, Monday, 2013]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.germainsoftware.apm.model.TimeDimension@14f272e7)
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
```

When I grep for the primary key value in the server log, I find:

```
[#|2013-11-04T18:02:18.846-0700|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/foo_jar/_bar.sql|_ThreadID=158;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=null;MethodName=null;|INSERT INTO TIME_DIMENSION (ID, DAY_OF_MONTH, DAY_OF_WEEK, DAY_OF_YEAR, HOUR, JWK_WEEK, JWK_YEAR, MINUTE, MONTH, MONTH_NAME, QUARTER, WEEKDAY, YEAR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3069178, 2, 6, 306, 15, 44, 2013, 55, 11, November, 2, Saturday, 2013]|#]
--
[#|2013-11-04T18:02:18.865-0700|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/foo_jar/_bar.sql|_ThreadID=158;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=null;MethodName=null;|INSERT INTO TIME_DIMENSION (ID, DAY_OF_MONTH, DAY_OF_WEEK, DAY_OF_YEAR, HOUR, JWK_WEEK, JWK_YEAR, MINUTE, MONTH, MONTH_NAME, QUARTER, WEEKDAY, YEAR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3069178, 3, 7, 307, 5, 44, 2013, 37, 11, November, 2, Sunday, 2013]|#]
--
```

The JPA annotated entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TIME_DIMENSION")
public class TimeDimension implements Dimension {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7496979683190776675L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TIME_DIM_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="TIME_DIM_SEQ",sequenceName="TIME_DIM_SEQ")
    private long id;

    ...
```

The database is Oracle 11g.  I haven't done anything to tell EclipseLink that the underlying database is Oracle.  Should I need to?  I tried recreating the index with
different options, and yes the increment is 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try adding `allocationSize=1`? As in: `@SequenceGenerator(name="TIME_DIM_SEQ",sequenceName="TIME_DIM_SEQ",allocationSize=1)` It is written here that you have to provide `allocationSize` equal to the `INCREMENT BY` of the sequence: [EclipseLink - PrimaryKey](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey)

Comment: How is the object causing the exception persisted?  Is it an existing object that might have had persist called on it?  If there is a problem with sequencing, it would occur frequently on inserts, so how often does this occur and under what situations?  What does the persistence.xml look like?

Comment: @Przemyslaw If you want to put that in an answer I'll give you the check mark. The key is that EclipseLink defaults the allocationSize to 50 when it isn't specified.  While I understand the performance benefits of such an approach, I never would have guessed that the default was not 1.

Comment: @Chris This is in a piece of code that executes periodically to extend the time dimension of a data warehouse.  The TimeDimension objects are newly constructed (id == 0L), the fields are set (other than id) and then they're passed to EntityManager.persist().  See my previous comment for the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding `allocationSize=1`? As in:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="TIME_DIM_SEQ",sequenceName="TIME_DIM_SEQ",allocationSi‌​ze=1)
```

It is written here that you have to provide `allocationSize` equal to the `INCREMENT BY` of the sequence:

[EclipseLink - Primary Key](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey)

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, the default value of allocationSize is 50 when omitted instead of the more intuitive (in my opinion) value of 1.